# Improve eslint highlighting in sublime-text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, eslint

I am using the `eslint` package for syntax checking in `sublime-text 3`. It is good, but when there is a mistake on a line, it just puts a fine red box around the offending character. This is very hard to see. With rubocop, a yellow box is drawn around the whole line. Is there anyway to do this with eslint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to make errors much clearer is go to the Sublime-Text Tools menu and choose `SublimeLinter>Mark Style`. Choose the `Fill` option and also check the `No Column Highlights Line` option.  This is not as clear as the rubocop outlining of the entire line, but it is certainly much easier to see.

Comment: In lieu of any other answers I will accept this, but hopefully someone will still come up with a better answer.